# Node Stack Overflow during linearHypothesis on model dummies

Tags: r, panel, dummy-variable, hypothesis-test

I hope you are having a fine sunday.

I have a panel dataset on bank stock returns of 868 banks across 94 time-periods in which I have created time- and bank-dummies. Having defined different regression configurations, I want to test the joint significance of the respective dummy sets using linearHypothesis().

Whilst this works completely fine for the time-dummies, I get the following error when attempting to test the bank-dummies:

```
Error in lengths(x) : node stack overflow
Error during wrapup: node stack overflow
```

Below is my codes for (i). Creating the dummies, (ii) Defining the lm()'s and (iii) Running the hypothesis tests:

```
panel$bank=cut(panel$Entity, breaks = c(0:868), labels=banklabels)
panel$time=cut(panel$Quarter, breaks = c(0:94), labels=timelabels)

bankdummyreg=lm(ret ~ l_ret + l_btm + l_roe + bank, data=panel)
timedummyreg=lm(ret ~ l_ret + l_btm + l_roe + time, data=panel)
--------------------------------------------------------
linearHypothesis(timedummyreg, matchCoefs(timedummyreg, "time"))
Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
timet2 = 0
---
timet94 = 0

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: ret ~ l_ret + l_btm + l_roe + time

Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F    Pr(>F)    
1  32739 865.29                                  
2  32646 623.00 93    242.29 136.52 < 2.2e-16 ***
--------------------------------------------------------
linearHypothesis(bankdummyreg, matchCoefs(bankdummyreg, "bank"))
Error in lengths(x) : node stack overflow
Error during wrapup: node stack overflow
```

Here are screenshots of my summary() and str() for my panel dataset:

[image: summary()]

[image: str()]

Having never encountered this error before, I can not find any information of this error in relation to linearHypothesis() either. I also find it confusing that the joint test on the time dummies works perfectly, seeing the two dummy sets were created in an identical manner. Any advise would be highly appreciated.